# Sharepoint 2013 Document library and search not displayed

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

I have a problem with document library, search zone' webparts which are hidden. I don't know the reason of it.

[image]

I have Windows 2008 R2 server, Sharepoint 2013 enterprise in 3 VMs (Front End, Back_End and Distributed Cache)

Any solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the search box immediately above the library and not the one in the top right corner? If so, the search box, and the other options just above the library, are hidden when any View Style other than "Default" is selected.